# How to create a multiple query form to filter an excel sheet using python?

Tags: python, excel, tkinter, kivy

1. I have been able to code working filter for an excel sheet (code attached).
2. Now, I want to create a GUI to select filter options from a drop down menu (I have tried but no success).

```
import pandas as pd
table1=pd.read_excel("sorted.xlsx")
table=pd.DataFrame(table1)
table2 = table[(table['LOG NO'] >int(float(variable.get()))) & (table.SensorID==variable1.get())]
print(table2)
table2.to_excel(excel_writer="success1.xlsx")
```

Comment: Please add the code what you tried so far. In the mentioned code there is nothing related to tkinter.